# Use core data to create multiple users

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I'm making an IOS app which needs to have the option to add users which the user can switch between. It will be as simple as the user entering in their name and the name being stored and added to a list to be selected. I'm using core data in another aspect of my project and would like to use it for this as well, although I am struggling to make something work. I have come up with the idea of creating an entity 'Users' and then adding string attributes in runtime for each user that a user adds. Is this possible and/or a good way to do it? If so, some guidance on the code would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You said you're using core data in another part of the project, this should be exactly the same. You create a very basic Entity `Users` with some attributes, then you create a new entity of `Users` type with each of the fields assigned to their respective properties. Then you do `context save`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out when I'm free.

Comment: But before I try just a question. Why am I creating two entities?

Comment: Create 1 `Users` entity in your CoreData model with the `NSString` attributes. Then run this command to create new instance of the `User` entity. You want 1 unique one for each new user. So you'll have multiple records in the `Users` table. `NSManagedObject *newUser = [NSEntityDescription
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Users"
    inManagedObjectContext:context];`